# JTextField is "empty" even if the user puts text into it

Tags: java, swing, text

Why is my `JTextField` "empty" even if I put text into it?

I am making a Java Program which creates a PDF File. I retrieve a text field input from `field3.getText();` but it is always `null`, even if it's not empty. Thus the text I want to be on the PDF is not showing.

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(font2, fontSize3);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(50, 690);
String name7;
try {
    name7 = GUI.field3.getText();
    contentStream.showText(name7);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
contentStream.endText();

//field3 piece of code in another class:


public class GUI {

    static String adress;
    static String name;
    static String country;
    static String postal;
    static String companyname;
    static String tel;
    static JTextField field2;
    static JTextField field3;
    static JTextField field_4;
    static JTextField field4;
    JTextField field5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public GUI() {
        field3 = new JTextField("");
    }
}
```

Comment: `field3 = new JTextField("");` should be `field3 = new JTextField(100);`

Comment: On a second thought - check if you closed the contentStream. Or modify this code to do a debug output to check whether this is a swing problem or not.

Comment: How to do debug mode?

Comment: I mean adding something like "System.out.println("name7: " name7);" so you see whether the variable is empty, or the PDF is empty.

Comment: Please have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html.
I can not see where field3 is added to a JPanel or a JFrame.

Comment: `null` is not empty. What is null, `GUI.field3`. Note, that field3 is a static field, but you assign it to a value when you create an instance of GUI. This is extremely poor design. Where do you create an instance of GUI? eg. GUI gui = new GUI(); would cause field3 to become non-null.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Tilman, its printing true for empty.

Comment: Tilman, bei mir wird true für isEmpty angezeigt. Aber ich schreibe Text in das JTextField.

Comment: So it's not a PDFBox problem, so you can remove that part. Currently I don't see where you're assigning a value into that field. Please apply what Andrew Thompson wrote, create a self-working code that shows the problem. Code with awt / swing isn't like that, see the comment by montardon.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the 'static' keyword from the variables initialized to make them instance variables.